# Using Sumproduct with shifting data range

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have monthly data set based on which I need to sum certain data points [sample format: Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q30Pk.png)

I am using sumproduct to get the required information in a separate sheet ([Example: Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IHe4.png))

Formula used in cell B3=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!$B$2:$D$2=Sheet2!B$2)*(Sheet1!$A$3:$A$13=Sheet2!$A3)*(Sheet1!$B$3:$D$13))

Now my challenge is, I have to manually change the data range in column D and E (in Sheet 2) for Nov-21. This data set is just a sample, I have a monthly data set for more than 16 months and it will keep on adding in future.

I am looking for a formula or combination, where I do not need to manually change the range. It checks for the month and automatically shift the data range.

Any help will be highly appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding the data manually each month, you could just summarise using additional empty row and when you add data, you would have to insert above this empty row. This way the summarising function should be automatically updated with newly moved range.